# Get and alert ID of select record from Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid running in MVC application and alert function in javaScript. I cannot make alert to work; i.e. ID of selected record. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here in code!

### JavaScript

```
function DeleteFunctionNavigation(e) {

    e.preventDefaults();

    var entityGrid = $("#AllFunctionsGrid_02").data("kendoGrid");

    var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());

    alert(selectedItem.Function_IDs);
}

function dataBound() {

}
```

### Kendo Grid

```
<div class="_grid_block">

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<App.DAL.Model.GetAllFunction_SP_Map>()
 .Name("AllFunctionsGrid_02")
                 .Columns(column =>
                 {
                     column.Bound(c => c.Function_IDs);
                     column.Bound(c => c.FunctionName);
                     column.Bound(c => c.Hierarchy_Level);
                     column.Bound(c => c.ControllerName);
                     column.Bound(c => c.ActionName);
                     column.Command(command => command.Custom("View").Click("DeleteFunctionNavigation"));                       
                 })
 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
 .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
 .Scrollable()
 .Filterable()
 .Groupable()
 .Sortable()
 .Selectable(selectable => selectable
 .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
 .Pageable(pageable => pageable
 .Refresh(true)
 .PageSizes(true)
 .ButtonCount(5))
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
 .Ajax()
 .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllFunctions", "SystemCore"))
 .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.Function_IDs))
)
.Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))


)
</div> <!--end _grid_block-->
```

Answer (score 1):

i have created a jsfiddle --

http://jsfiddle.net/mga6f/390/

code:-

```
 $("#grid tr").click(function() {
     var entityGrid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

     var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());

     alert(selectedItem.id);

 });
```

with above code it is working fine..

i have tried above given code with http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/selection (grid in this demo) and put below given code in console and then selected row then it is showing the alert..

```
$("#rowSelection tr").click(function() {
    var entityGrid = $("#rowSelection").data("kendoGrid");

    var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select());

    alert(selectedItem.ShipCountry);

});
```

Comment: why I am getting null when I do for selectedItem ---- var selectedItem = entityGrid.dataItem(entityGrid.select()); --- alert(selectedItem )

Comment: I have found issue is!! if row is selected then my code send id but i want to do with button not selected row

Comment: if needed then work on change event of grid or onSelect